# Reading images from a folder using flutter

Tags: image, flutter, directory, path

i want to read some images that are in "myImages" folder in storage of my phone. i need to list only these images. how can i open myImages folder and list images in that by flutter?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Image.file(File('FilePath'))` like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Image.file(File('FilePath')),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank so mush, the folder name is "myImages" and it is in my storage on main path. then how can put this path instead of 'FilePath' that you write?

Comment: You can use `path_provider_ex: ^1.0.1` for find sdcard path.